# What is the different between remain and retain?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I have a sentence: "In this study, we basically **retained** the functions of these core software components intact during the development phase. "
Can we use **remain** instead of retain in this sentence?

When I checked the usage of remain in a dictionary, it said

> You can say that something remains when it still exists.

E.g.
1.Many of the differences in everyday life remain. 
2.The wider problem remains. 
3. There remains deep mistrust of his government.

So I want to say the functions of these software still exist in the development phase. They are not removed. How can't I use remain?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Your question is a little unclear. These verbs are different types of verbs, and have different meanings. "Retain" is a transitive verb and requires an object, while "remain" is an intransitive verb and would not work as a direct replacement in your sentence. In other words, you cannot say "...we basically _remained_ the functions..." However, the sentence _could_ be re-worded to take the verb "remain".

Comment: The difference between ***retain*** and ***remain*** is so great I think it's far too basic for an ELU question. On the other hand, *You can say that something **obtains** when it **starts to** exist.*

Comment: @Cascabel  Now I see the big difference between these two words. The functions remained intact ...or we retain the funtions...Thank you!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you! _Obtain_ is used when it starts to exist? I found one sentence in the dictionary - The practice still obtains in some areas of England. It does not seem like the practice starts to exist in this areas but already exists for a while..Do I understand this correctly?

Comment: It's really a metaphoric extension from the underlying ***obtain = get, acquire***, leading to OED's definition 7b: *To be prevalent, customary, or established; to be in force or in vogue; to hold good; to subsist or exist; to be the case.* There's also an element of ***win, gain*** in the underlying sense, reflected in the metaphoric usage being more appropriate when something ***comes into** existence*, rather than ***maintains** its existence / **endures***.

Answer (score 2):

**Retain** is a transitive verb meaning 'to keep' something.
**Remain** is an intransitive verb meaning to stay in the same place, or to continue to exist.
In your example sentence, you would have to omit 'we' and say "The functions of these core software components remained intact..."

Comment: Please don't endorse such obvious candidates for being put on hold.